# ImportError: No module named _tkinter_finder

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am packaging my application using `pyinstaller`. It created the binary file, but it is not working. When I load the application on terminal I see this error

```
[9854] LOADER: Running BC_GUI_Client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FALCON_BC_CLIENT/BC_GUI_Client.py", line 145, in <module>
  File "PIL/ImageTk.py", line 127, in __init__
  File "PIL/ImageTk.py", line 192, in paste
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 687, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple)
ImportError: No module named _tkinter_finder
[9854] Failed to execute script BC_GUI_Client
```

I am using python 2.7 and installed pyinstaller 3.3
Anything wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide your spec file (or the flags you run for pyinstaller), as well as the output of the PyInstaller build? Is it working normally, but fails after you build the exe? Are you on windows 10?

Answer (score 28):

I was able to resolve a simiar issue by running pyinstaller with the following option added in the command:

```
--hidden-import='PIL._tkinter_finder'
```

Your command should look like this:

```
pyinstaller module.py --hidden-import='PIL._tkinter_finder'
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this helped me as well, the same problem.