# Python executable file crashes after compiled using pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, compiler-errors, pycharm, pyinstaller

I had this POS System that runs smooth when ran on the pycharm itself. It includes icons, one main py file and another py file for the pop up calculator. I tried to use pyinstaller using pycharm's terminal with "pyinstaller mainGUI.py" and even added --onefile but after being compiled successfully, it won't let me open it. I browse through dist folder and open the executable file and it just gives me a hint of my main program's color background and disappear like nothing happened.

I'll be attaching what the GUI should look like and here's the video of what it shows and happens when you run the exec file
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx2cF.jpg)
https://streamable.com/rw4kac

btw I'm using debian os 64bit

pyinstaller mainGUI.py --onefile -w

Comment: Do you think the debian system can execute ".exe" files?

Comment: dunno, honestly Im new to linux and I just used debian because the all-in-one pc I bought has low specs enough just to run linux. Got this idea with yt tutorials and threads here about compiling pyfiles in ubuntu. They use pyinstaller aswell and they work. Do you have another way to make this pyfile execute with a click of an icon.

Comment: Create a [mre].  Try compiling without the `-w` flag and then starting the executable from the command line.

Comment: @Alexander same results, but I saw the error. Do you know how to fix this image error? https://ibb.co/3pVhgVk
https://ibb.co/ZSYBsHR
https://ibb.co/0n35CPN

Comment: The first link is the error from executing the file, the second link is the line 1035 in the py file and the last link is the project folder where all the images and main py file is located. I think pyinstaller doesn't include the pictures when compiling

Comment: Yes... My instructions were not to fix the issue, they were to discover what the issue was.  And clearly the issue is because your code is referencing a file that doesn't exist. Switch_open.png is not where it is supposed to be.

Comment: just solved this by removing --windowed and importing PIL thanks a lot! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680429/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter-finder